# How to debug working thread not interrupting it?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a remote working tornado `WebSocketHandler` server.

Are there ways to assign a breakpoint to remote working thread in `pdb` style (or somehow else), to attach to the thread and to debug it? I say about debugging 'on-the-fly'.

The thread has not special imports (or other settings) for debugging. If it has matter, I can setup any settings for the future.

The fact that the thread is stopped and users start to wait is normal.

Or is there a method to debug remote threads with unexpected errors which are not reported by interpreter?